# Issues using Owl Carousel as a custom element with Polymer

Tags: polymer, owl-carousel

I am trying to incorporate Owl Carousel into a custom web component using Polymer. I have successfully managed to do this however Owl Carousel doesn't behave correctly.

When the carousel is dragged using touch or mouse input, it resets to the beginning. Using Owl Carousel outside of a Polymer custom element functions correctly.

So say I clicked the navigation buttons to see items 5,6,7 in my carousel, when I drag via mouse or touch then the carousel would reset to item 1.

Does any one have any ideas why this issue could be happening?

```
            <link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
            <link rel="import" href="../core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
            <link rel="import" href="../core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
            <link rel="import" href="../core-icons/core-icons.html">
            <link rel="import" href="../paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
            <link rel="import" href="../paper-fab/paper-fab.html">
            <link rel="import" href="../paper-shadow/paper-shadow.html">

            <!--  jQuery 1.7+  -->
            <script src="../../jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

            <!-- Include js plugin -->
            <script src="../../owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>


            <polymer-element name="my-element">
              <template>
                <style>

                  #owl .item{
                    background: #a1def8;
                    display: block;
                    color: #FFF;
                    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
                    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
                    border-radius: 3px;
                    text-align: center;
                    width: 170px;
                    height: 200px;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                  }

                </style>

                <!-- Important Owl stylesheet -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">

                <!-- Default Theme -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../owl-carousel/owl.theme.css">

                  <div id="owl" class="owl-carousel owl-theme"></div>
              </template>
              <script>
                Polymer({
                  domReady: function() {
                    $(this.$.owl).owlCarousel({
                      jsonPath : "../../data.json",
                      navigation: true,
                      pagination: false
                    });
                  }
                });
              </script>
            </polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have concluded that this is an issue related to the Shadow DOM. Owl Carousel works with the Light DOM but wrapping it up in a custom element will move it to the Shadow DOM where Owl Carousel cannot function correctly.